# Append function in loop appends to all entries of a nested list

Tags: python, list, loops, append, nested-lists

I am trying to write code that allocates jobs to 20 different students. These jobs are randomly chosen from a list of jobs which - with a binary matrix - also indicates, whether student `i` can do that job.

```
starting_solution = [[]] * 20
for i in range(20):
    counter = 0
    while True and counter < 10000:
        counter += 1
        possible_index = random.choice(list(set([x for x in range(len(order_data))])
                                            - set(done_jobs)))
    if job_matrix[possible_index][i] == '1':
```

If student `i` can do the job, the code checks whether the student has enough time left:

```
    if sum(student_durations[i]) - student_durations[i][-1] + possible_time < 28800:
```

If this is the case, I would like to add the job to the schedule of student i, which is entry i in the nested list created earlier. Now, if I use the following code, for some reason the job gets added to all entries (0 - 19) of the schedule.

```
    starting_solution[i].append(possible_index)
```

I tried a lot of different things, including printing the list and `i` before appending and after. I always corresponds to only one value and if I print `starting_solution[i]`, it also outputs the correct entry.

Comment: Try `starting_solution = [[] for _ in range(20)]` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply! Makes sense when looking at the duplicate question.